# WDS Adding Boot Image and Install Image with no Installation Disk

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, installation, images

I am working through a lab dealing with Windows Deployment Service in Windows Server 2012. In order to progress I need to add an Install image and a Boot Image. All documentation I can find, including my textbook are instructing me to find them in my installation DVD. I Do not have a DVD with the Windows Server 2012 install on it however because I am using an VM created with an ISO file I downloaded from microsoft technet. How can I get a boot and install image for windows server 2012 (.wim files) since I do not have an actual install disk?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I realized you can use winrar to open the ISO and extract the boot.wim and the install.wim.